# Is it possible to use JWT Bearer received from MSAL (MS identity platform) to access MS AppCenter API?

Tags: azure-ad-msal, visual-studio-app-center

I am writting Android app to call MS Appcenter API (https://openapi.appcenter.ms/) and want the users of the app to login with their credential so i can not use pregenerated tokens.

I am able to get JWT token using MSAL android library com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:0.2.2

If I try to call the API "https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/user" with `Authorization: Bearer ...` header I got response `{"message":"Fail to verify JWT Token.","statusCode":401,"code":"Unauthorized"}`

Neither `X-API-Token` works with the token (not a surprise)

It is interesting if I lookup JWT token from GoogleChrome dev tools and use it either with curl: `curl -X GET "https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/user" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ..."` or hardcode into my android app I get success response.

So it is definitely possible to use "some" JWT token to access Appcenter API, but it is unclear is it possible to get working JWT token from MSAL and what I should use instead it if it is not possible.

My first suggestion is I have to use the correct "SCOPE" audience, but it is not documented and quick guesses did not help

The way I get JWT token from MSAL (have success to get it)

```
val SCOPES = arrayOf("email")

val authClientApplication = PublicClientApplication(context, clientId)

authClientApplication.acquireToken(
  context,
  SCOPES,
  object:AuthenticationCallback {
                override fun onSuccess(authenticationResult: AuthenticationResult?) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Successfully authenticated");
                    Log.d(TAG, "ID Token: " + authenticationResult?.idToken);
                    token = authenticationResult?.idToken
                }
...
```

The way I try to use the JWT token (fails with 401 if JWT got from MSAL)

```
val client = OkHttpClient()
val request = Request
            .Builder()
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+token)
            .url("https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/user")
            .build()

        try {
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback{
...
```

JWT from MSAL decoded content (not-working):

```
{
  "ver": "2.0",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXX-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad/v2.0",
  "sub": "AAAAANNNNNAAAAAAAAAAAAJgzlyDKyV8iUg4I-js52sY",
  "aud": "long-numbers-of-azure-app-client-id",
  "exp": 1561271401,
  "iat": 1561184701,
  "nbf": 1561184701,
  "name": "My Name",
  "preferred_username": "my@email",
  "oid": "00000000-0000-0000-cd89-898098098",
  "email": "my@email",
  "tid": "long-numbers-of-something",
  "aio": "BASE64lookingGarbage"
}
```

JWT from GoogleChrome session decoded content (working):

```
{
  "id": "35980548-0000-4c1d-9d9c-2318dc17a4a1",
  "origin": "appcenter",
  "iat": 1561184258,
  "exp": 1561187858,
  "aud": "Bifrost",
  "iss": "Heimdall",
  "sub": "user"
}
```